# Integer value to decimal only last 2 digit in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Integer or String value like 6250 or 125...
I need like below example. Is it possible in Javascript?

```
6250 to 62,50
7856 to 78,56
125 to 1,25
050 to 0,50
```

Comment: You want comma or decimal point?

Comment: @R.T.decimal good solution for me...

Comment: Why does 6250 converts to 62,5 **1** ?

Comment: So what did you try so far?

Comment: @Youness Sorry I need 6250 to >62,50

Comment: yes its all dione and tested see my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var i = parseInt('6250'),
    res = (i / 100).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: @mplungjan. Yeah. Does not correct result. But I round 0,25 and multiples. Worked for me. Thank you again.

Comment: I do not understand your comment

Answer (score 1):

Just try following code..

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dgmyrskk/)**

```
var str = "567";
var len=str.length;
if(len>2){
  var res = str.substring(0, len-2)+','+str.substring(len-2,len);
  alert(res);
}
```